# Display joystick input in java

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

How can I make java display joystick input whenever I press a button?

I'm using *lwjgl*. I tried using this loop I found online but is there any alternatives without using this?

I want it to be like a *keyListener* that whenever I press a button in the joystick It would display something.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;

public class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // to initialize. Most GLFW functions will not work without this.
        if (!GLFW.glfwInit())
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
        int qanbainput;


        for (qanbainput = 0; qanbainput <= GLFW.GLFW_JOYSTICK_LAST; qanbainput++) {
            if (!GLFW.glfwJoystickPresent(qanbainput)) continue;
            System.out.println("JoyStick(" + qanbainput + ")Name:" +
                GLFW.glfwGetJoystickName(qanbainput) + " " +
                GLFW.glfwGetGamepadName(qanbainput));
            break;
        }
        if (qanbainput > GLFW.GLFW_JOYSTICK_LAST) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int count1 = 0;
            FloatBuffer floatBuffer = GLFW.glfwGetJoystickAxes(qanbainput);
            System.out.print("Axes:");
            while (floatBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                float axes = floatBuffer.get();
                System.out.print(count1 + "," + axes + " ");
                count1++;
            }

            int count2 = 0;
            System.out.print("Button:");
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = GLFW.glfwGetJoystickButtons(qanbainput);
            while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                byte button = byteBuffer.get();
                System.out.print(count2 + "," + button + " ");
                count2++;
            }
            System.out.println();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the following web page:

https://www.lwjgl.org/guide

Comment: Yeah, but I don't really understand It,  I'm doing this for a project.  I just want a simple program that can display something from a joystick, like every button press shows something. Can you give some tips?

Comment: Have you read the following:
// Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
  glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
   if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
  });

Comment: Will this work on a gamepad/joystick? How should I write this on a program? I'm really sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: Just try first.

Comment: Or you may go to their forum for assistance:
http://forum.lwjgl.org/